# Java Recursion: How to avoid the last comma when write 1..n seperated by commas in one line. See full task description inside

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following task:

Write a ***recursive*** void method that takes a ***single (positive) int argument*** n and writes the integers 1, 2, . . . , n to the screen.

What I tried so far is:

```
public static void write1ToNInOneLine(int n){
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    } 
    else // n is two or more digits long:
    {
        write1ToNInOneLine(n - 1);
        System.out.print(n + ",");
    }
}
```

but obviously I have the last redundant comma on output.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code:

```
public static void write1ToNInOneLine(int n){
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    } 
    else // n is two or more digits long:
    {
        write1ToNInOneLine(n - 1);
        System.out.print(n + ",");
    }
}
```

is that you are not handling the end-case correctly.

> single (positive) int argument n and writes the integers 1, 2, . . . ,
> n to the screen.

In your case, the end-case is when the `n = 1`. Moreover, you are doing `System.out.print(n + ",");` which means that the after the last element you will add `","`. Because the end case is "1" it is better to do `System.out.print(","+ n);` so that the last element (*i.e.,* `n = n`) will not have ",", and handle the case when `n = 1` so that you do not add `","` before 1. Like as follows:

```
public static void write1ToNInOneLine(int n){
    if (n == 1){
        System.out.print(n);
    }
    else if (n > 1){
        write1ToNInOneLine(n - 1);
        System.out.print(","+ n);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Alternatively:

```
public static String write1ToNInOneLine(final int n) {
    return ((n > 1) ? write1ToNInOneLine(n - 1) + "," : "") + n;
}
```

and then:

```
System.out.println(write1ToNInOneLine(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are already some other answers here, but just to show that there can be many different ways to achieve the same output, a slightly different and more concise version could be something like:

```
public static void write1ToNInOneLine(final int n) {
    if(n > 1)
    {
        write1ToNInOneLine(n - 1);
        System.out.print(',');
    }
    System.out.print(n);
}
```

When called like so: `write1ToNInOneLine(6)`, the output is:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 1):

The least code that I can get to achieve this is:

```
public static void write1ToNInTwoLines(int i) {
    if (i > 1) write1ToNInOneLine(i-1);
    System.out.print(i > 1? "," + i : i);
}
```

This has a couple of benefits that I can see:

- it is completely self contained (return type void) - the caller does not have to print
- it does exactly what it needs to and only that (e.g. no use empty speech-marks "")

to call you invoke:

```
write1ToNInTwoLines(10);
```

and will print:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10